# Change view without transition

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

The answer to this might be very simple, but I don't know it. The question is, how do I change views in my flex mobile app without using any transitions.

Here is an example of how I usually do it using pushView

```
var slideTrans:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition(); 
slideTrans.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.DOWN;
navigator.pushView(views.SettingsView, null, null, slideTrans);
```

So I want to know how to change the view but without any transition animation. Do I still use pushView, or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you would still use pushView, try passing null for the transition class

```
navigator.pushView(views.SettingsView, null, null, null);


pushView(viewClass:Class, 
data:Object = null, 
context:Object = null, 
transition:spark.transitions:ViewTransitionBase = null):void
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work when I try it out. It just gives me the standard push transition, which is, slide the new view in from right to left.

Comment: Ah, try adding navigator.defaultPushTransition = null to your base mxml file

Comment: @f-a can you update your original post with that point. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I can't try it out right now but from what I remember, you simply have to define the transition as `new ViewTransitionBase()`. The basic transition does nothing.

You can also define the default transition that's used when none (null) is passed :

```
var emptyTransition = new ViewTransitionBase();
navigator.defaultPopTransition = emptyTransition;
navigator.defaultPushTransition = emptyTransition;
```

Here's some info on transitions that does not include empty one but interesting anyway : [Define transitions in a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS8b1c39bd7e9fc36459dd44a012cbc814595-8000.html)